# Wordpress login logout menu with sub menus

Tags: drop-down-menu, submenu

I try to make word press site by my self.
i need to add login to main nav-menu.
with sub menu 
"register" (link http://www.vcanade.ca/register/)

after user logged in, menu has to change to username with sub menus
"profile" (link http://www.vcanade.ca/your-profile/) and
"logout"

does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the buttons on the nav menu ('register','profile','logout').

Give each button a unique ID and then use CSS rules to hide the inappropriate buttons:

```
body.logged-in #my-register-button {
  display: none;
}
body:not(.logged-in) #my-register-button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This works because native WordPress gives the body tag the class "logged-in" whenever a user is logged in.

Comment: well, this not that easy for me :) i thought i have to use function.php file. how can i create this buttons?

Comment: go to the backend (ie /wp-admin) and navigate to appearance -> menus, then add the appropriate page or custom link to the menu. It will appear in the nav bar.

You can use 'screen options' in the top-right to enable CSS classes the give each button a unique class instead of a unique ID.

Alternatively, you can write some jQuery or JS to append the HTML nodes at run time.